EPPlus Get/Set/Add/Remove Worksheet Custom Properties
I'm using EPPlus for Excel document generation and editing. Does EPPlus include a way to access worksheet custom properties?
Excel Interop for reference.
Tried the EPPLus OfficeProperties class, but that does not appear to have anything to do with worksheet custom properties.
